# How to design the tables/entities in NoSQL DB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I do my first steps in NoSQL databases, thus I would like to hear the best practices about implementing the following requirement.

Let suppose I have a messages database, which is powered by MongoDB engine. This DB contains a collection of documents, where each document has the following fields:

- time stamp;
- message author/source;
- message content.

Now, I want to build a list of authors/sources in order to add some metadata about each source. In the case of the classical RDBMS, I would define a table `tblSources` where I would store the names of the message sources and all additional meta-data (or links to the relevant tables) for each author.

What is the right approach to such task in NoSQL/MongoDB world?

Comment: Any particular reason you have chosen to use NOSQL over a traditional RDBMS? Because this sounds very much like a task suited to the latter

Comment: Actually, I would like to gain an experience with the `NoSQL`, that's why I decided to use `MongoDB` and not `RDBMS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how you want to use the data.  NoSQL dbs are generally not designed with fast joins in mind but they are still capable of doing joins and storing foreign keys.

Your options here are really

1. duplicate data aka store the author metadata in every document.  This might be better in the case where you are really trying to optimize lookups and use Mongo as a key value store
2. Join on foreign key - this is pretty similar to how you would use a RDBMS